# Supervisor config user option in program section

Tags: tornado, supervisord

I have a Tornado program, and all the relative python lib installed in a non-root user called bob by:

```
pip install --user xxx
```

Now I want to run it in supervisor:

```
[program:testpro]
command=python /path/to/myfile.py
user=bob    ; set the user to bob
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/path/to/log
numproces=1
autostart=true
```

but it failed, in supervisorctl status:

```
testpro            FATAL     Exited too quickly (process log may have details)
```

I see the log and find it can't import relative python lib, so it it not run as bob.

then I change to :

```
[program:testpro]
command=sudo -u bob -i python /path/to/myfile.py
;user=bob ;comment this
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/path/to/log
numproces=1
autostart=true
```

and it run ok

So, what does the option `user` do? and how can I config the run-as user in an option?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I have solved this problem:

add `environment` option in program section:

```
environment=HOME="/home/bob",USER="bob"
```

See [Supervisor doc - Subprocess Environment](http://supervisord.org/subprocess.html#subprocess-environment):

> No shell is executed by supervisord when it runs a subprocess, so
>   environment variables such as USER, PATH, HOME, SHELL, LOGNAME, etc.
>   are not changed from their defaults or otherwise reassigned. This is
>   particularly important to note when you are running a program from a
>   supervisord run as root with a user= stanza in the configuration.
>   Unlike cron, supervisord does not attempt to divine and override
>   “fundamental” environment variables like USER, PATH, HOME, and LOGNAME
>   when it performs a setuid to the user defined within the user= program
>   config option. If you need to set environment variables for a
>   particular program that might otherwise be set by a shell invocation
>   for a particular user, you must do it explicitly within the
>   environment= program config option. An example of setting these
>   enviroment variables is as below.

```
[program:apache2]
command=/home/chrism/bin/httpd -c "ErrorLog
/dev/stdout" -DFOREGROUND user=chrism
environment=HOME="/home/chrism",USER="chrism"
```

Comment: Note that if you're running a `[fcgi-program:foo]` you might need to set socket's user to, say _www-data_. Following works:
    `[fcgi-program:foo]`
    `user=www-data`
    `environment=USER="www-data"`
    `# rest of the options`

Answer (score 3):

You can use directory option.

"When supervisord daemonizes, switch to this directory. This option can include the value"

```
[program:testpro]
command=python /path/to/myfile.py
directory=/path/to/
user=bob    ; set the user to bob
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/path/to/log
numproces=1
autostart=true
```

Comment: not use. I want to know the difference between set `user` vs `sudo -u bob`?

Comment: hi, I have solved this problem, you can see my answer.

Answer (score -1):

Don't forget to restart supervisord itself, such as with `/etc/init.d/supervisord restart` because otherwise your conf changes are not being picked up and it will keep running your service as root.

Comment: You don't need to restart supervisord itself. Either use the `supervisorctl update` command to reload the configuration and restart affected programs or groups, or use `supervisorctl reread` to only update configuration, before selectively restarting services as needed. Even `supervisorctl reload` is a better idea than restarting the process via the init script, as the latter ensures processes are properly shut down first before the supervisor daemon restarts.

Comment: Last but not least, this is **at most** an additional remark, it does not address the question itself.